# Cant install cmdstan: g++ comand not found

Tags: mingw, rtools

I'm tyrying to install CmdStan on Win 11.
That I've done:

1. Install the C++ toolchain using RTools 4.3
2. Adding RTools43 bin paths to the PATH environment variable
3. Building mingw32-make using pacman -Sy mingw-w64-x86_64-make as suggested in this thread.
4. git clone https://github.com/stan-dev/cmdstan.git --recursive
5. cd cmdstan

And there's I got problem:
Use mingw32-make build.

I get error:

> expr: syntax error: unexpected argument 'line' /usr/bin/sh: line 1:
> g++: command not found make/program:19: *** target pattern contains no
> '%'.  Stop.

Comment: Why did you add the Python tag?

Comment: Means what it says, no? You need to install g++ (the GNU C++ compiler). `make` _just runs makefiles_, it doesn't include any compilers those makefiles may try to invoke.

Comment: If RTools claims to have included a C++ toolchain, find the name of the executable for the compiler it provided and set the variable `CXX` to point to that compiler. Or, if it did already include a copy of g++, make sure that copy of g++ is found at a location in your PATH.

Answer (score 0):

I've checked my PATH's. And found that my path lead to emtry folder.
I found folder with exe-files, that I need and correct PATHs.
My prevision path contain only mingw32-make.exe:
C:\rtools43\mingw64\bin
New path contains all exe's:
C:\rtools43\ucrt64\bin